# javax.inject.Qualifier been ignored by Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have defined the following qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface DefaultObjectSerializer
{

}
```

And annotated a Factory Bean with it:

```
@DefaultObjectSerializer
public class DefaultObjectSerializerFactoryBean implements SmartFactoryBean<ObjectSerializer>
```

I then try to use that dependency in an object:

```
public static class TestObjectSerializerAware
{

    @Inject
    @DefaultObjectSerializer
    private ObjectSerializer objectSerializer;

    public ObjectSerializer getObjectSerializer()
    {
        return objectSerializer;
    }
}
```

I would expected that class to be injected with the factory bean's return object. Instead, I get this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.mule.api.serialization.ObjectSerializer] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:

Are JSR-330 qualifiers not working in Spring 4.1.5?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen `@Qualifier` used in this way; are you sure you're doing it correctly? Usually you give a name to a `@Bean`, annotate your class with `@Component` (or `@Controller`, `@Service`, etc), then annotate the field like so: `@Qualifier("myObjectSerializer") private ObjectSerializer objectSerializer;`

Comment: The Qualifier annotation in my example is not Spring one but the javax.inject.Qualifier one. Actually the same thing happens with @Named. This turned out to actually be a bug and filed the issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12914

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the package in the title. Post the fact that this was a bug as an answer and accept it.